# D3js X axis rounds down ticks for some browser widths

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3js v5, with an Ordinal scale for my X axis on a line chart.

```
this.x = scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(axisXDataTruncated.labels)
  .range(axisXDataTruncated.range);
```

When I draw my x axis using this:

```
 this.root
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${this.height})`)
    .call(
      axisBottom(this.x).tickFormat((data: string | number) =>
        formatter(
          this.graphDataMerged.lineChartOptions.axis.x.format,
          data,
          this.graphDataMerged.lineChartOptions.axis.x.currency
        )
      )
    );
```

I'm using string labels (['Week 1'. 'Week 2',... 'Week 26'] as labels.

When I have a long number of labels, the x axis, discards the last labels and crops to a certain value. For example, with 26 values. Tha last label shows as 25, which is shown at the very end of the x axis.

Because the dots and lines of my chart includes the value at position 26, the axis and the dots don't match.

If I expand the browser's width, the last value of the x axis magically appears.

What could I be doing wrong? Is it a bug in v5?

Comment: Please create an example made with bare Javascript.

Comment: If this is a line chart your scale should not be `scaleOrdinal`. However, if you still want to keep the discrete/categorical domain, try a point scale (`scalePoint`) setting its padding.